# Unable to sign in in visual studio community 2017

Tags: visual-studio, error-logging, visual-studio-2017

I was using visual studio 2017 normally and i was signed in and i had no issues. but suddenly i notice my self signed out, when i tried to sign in again the message shown in the image below pop up even without entering my account info, just when i press on the sign in label on the top-right corner, this message shows up, if i pressed `OK`, it will keep on showing `"We're getting things ready"` but it will freeze on this status, i made the lastest update today and it didn't solve the issue, can someone help me please, because it is saying that my usage will be expired soon, so i need to login.

**The Error Picture:**

[image]

Comment: I made a working (IE) proxy connection, then i and made VS connect through it by modifying the `.config` file, but now it doesn't connect to the network, still no luck....